# Deploy maven multi module project in GC

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, google-cloud-platform

I'm new to google cloud and I need to deploy my java application there.
Currently it consists of 1 one web-module and directory structure looks like this:

- clinic_project

  - acms-frontend

    - pom.xml
  - pom.xml

And start script:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    nohup mvn clean install

    serv=acms-frontend
    cd $serv
    nohup mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring.profiles.active="dev" -DAUTH0_CLIENT_ID=".." -DAUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET=".." -DACMS_CRYPTO_KEY=".." -DACMS_NODE_NAME="n/a" -DACMS_POD_IP="n/a" -DACMS_POD_NAMESPACE="n/a" -DACMS_POD_NAME="n/a"
```

Inside web-module I have *.yml* file with default port and other variables.
I've installed gcloud SDK and understand how I can deploy single module application.

But how can I tell google cloud to deploy my multi-module project with commands sequence from script?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to deploy multiple modules, you can do so with the following command: `gcloud app deploy ~/my_app/app.yaml ~/my_app/another_service.yaml` as mentioned in the `gcloud app deploy` [documentation examples](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/deploy).

Make sure to add the module/service name in the app.yaml files as mentioned in [this other document](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#runtime_and_app_elements), otherwise you may run into some naming issues with them.

Hope you find this useful!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For the full answer I also wanted to know how can I pass command line arguments from my script `-Dspring.profiles.active="dev" -DAUTH0_CLIENT_ID = ....` so that project will be deployed?